# How to convert css rules to flutter style

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have some css, how to convert this css to flutter style

```css
background: linear-gradient(262.06deg, #03737D 0%, #14373A 101.04%);
```

I have tried this but not It is not working like I want

```dart
return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            stops: [
                    0,
                    1.1
                  ],
            colors: [
                    constants.customColors.gradiant03,
                    constants.customColors.gradiant14
                  ])),
            )
);
```

Comment: `not working as I want` means nothing specific really. I'd add images showing desired and actual output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this:

```dart
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Title")),
    body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerRight,
                end: Alignment.centerLeft,
                colors: [Color(0xff03737D), Color(0xff14373A)]
                )
            ),
        height: 60,
        child: Text("Checking gradient bg", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
));
```

**CSS output**:

[image]

**Flutter output**:

[image]

Comment: so verbose for single line of CSS

Comment: @ali80, not exactly, as if you can see that the code snippets contains other elements and attributes which can be removed. 

Comment: you can shave of 4-5 lines,it is still at least 10 line for 1 line of css, I like Vue or React not ditching the good old css much better

Answer (score -7):

Try with the snippet below ..

**CSS**:

```css
background: linear-gradient(262.06deg, #03737D 0%, #14373A 101.04%);
```

**Flutter**:

```dart
new Container( 
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: new DecorationImage(
      image: new ExactAssetImage('linear-gradient(262.06deg, rgb(3, 115, 125) 0%, rgb(20, 55, 58) 101.04%'),
      fit: BoxFit.auto,
      repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
    ),
  )
),
```

Comment: Did you check your answer? It seems that you don't understand how `ExactAssetImage` works